# Oracle APEX Presenting Data Slower When Row Count bigger than 1.000.000

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

When type query in SQL Developer, it return data less than a second. When do the same in Oracle APEX it take much more time, over 5 seconds. I go in DEBUG section to see what's wrong, and it return this to me:

```
-IR binding: "APXWS_MAX_ROW_CNT" value="1000000"
```

I figure it out, that it returns more than 1.000.000 rows, and that's why is slower. But don't know how to fix it, to get approximately the same time as in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Leave the Maximum Row Count property null, so classic reports won't fetch all the way to this number and interactive reports won't introduce the analytic function count(*) over ().

Don't use a Pagination Type with a Z, so classic reports won't fetch all rows and interactive reports again won't introduce count(*) over ()."

source: http://rwijk.blogspot.ca/2016/11/performance-aspects-of-apex-reports.html 
(I saved it in the wayback machine too if the link goes away: http://web.archive.org/web/20170706183715/http://rwijk.blogspot.ca/2016/11/performance-aspects-of-apex-reports.html

Answer (score 1):

Put some limits on `Maximum Row Count` and `Maximum Rows per Page` can help you to mitigate loading. 
You never had same performance as SQL Developer in a web page apex or not.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that can't be so quick as in SQL Developer, but 6,7 times slower? P.S. How to increase Maximum Row Count?

Comment: Set Maximum Row Count in tab attributes of yours IR.

Comment: Performance depends by multiple factor (browser, network, IR implementation....). APEX version 5.0/5.1?

Comment: Apex Version is  5.0.1.00.06 What's next?

Comment: Set your SQL Developer SQL Array Fetch Size to 1000000 and check the difference again, because that would be closer to apples to apples. Or set APEX max count to 100